# Get express.js query param dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have this code, which checks if a argument is whether given or not and has a value or not.

```
const isSetAndNotEmpty = (parameter) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        //Define param ( is there a way to make this working with the parameter from above )
        const param = req.query.id;

        //Check param
        if (!param || typeof (param) === 'undefined') {
            return res.json({
                success: false,
                message: `Argument '${parameter}' is missing or empty!`
            });
        }
        next();
    };
};
```

Is there a way to give the param variable the same value as the parameter?
Because the way I see it works is that whatever I give the **req.query.xxx** it will take it as a query parameter.

Just saying **req.query.parameter** is not working because of the reason that it will be taken as a query parameter.

Comment: `req.query[parameter]`

Comment: @Enve Oh thanks! If you can write it as a  answer I am glad to accept it :D